# regex for time 24 hour format in extjs 3

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

I am little weak in regular expression. Can anybody help me in finding regular expression for time (in 24 hour format) in extjs

Thank you.

Comment: Check http://regexlib.com for standard regex cases like this.

Comment: Is it for input validation from control? or parsing any server data? add some context where you use this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to. The fine folks at Sencha went through a lot of trouble so that developers like us don't have to mess with this sort of thing.

```
// returns null if parse failed, or Date object is successful
var mydate = Ext.Date.parse(inputString, "G:i");
```

For more information, check the API docs for [Ext.Date](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Date)

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
'/^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/'
```

Not sure if it works on extis, if not you can always translate it back to the syntax uses in extis.

Answer (score 0):

Try out

```
^(20|21|22|23|[01]\d|\d)(([:][0-5]\d){1,2})$
```

or you can use

```
([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]
```

For more info visit [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-time-in-24-hours-format-with-regular-expression/)